# conditionally authenticate one part e.g /secure of the application on Windows Authentication and rest of the application on OAuth2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication

I am using [HTTPListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) with OWIN to host asp.net webapi as a windows service.I would like to conditionally authenticate one part e.g /secure of the application on Windows Authentication and rest of the application on OAuth2.This is easy in IIS but turned out not that straight forward with OWIN+HttpListenr.

I followed this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/enabling-windows-authentication-in-katana) to setup the windows Authentication but it is for the whole application

```cs
    namespace KatanaSelfHost
    {
        class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                HttpListener listener = 
                    (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
                listener.AuthenticationSchemes = 
                    AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;

                app.Run(context =>
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HttpListener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.authenticationschemeselectordelegate(v=vs.110).aspx) to add some conditional logic.

```
namespace KatanaSelfHost
    {
        class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                HttpListener listener = 
                    (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];                    
listener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate = 
    new AuthenticationSchemeSelector (AuthenticationSchemeForClient);


                app.Run(context =>
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            }
        }
    }
    static AuthenticationSchemes AuthenticationSchemeForClient(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client authentication protocol selection in progress...");
        // check the url here
        if (request.RawUrl.Contains("/secure"))
        {
            return AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
        }
        else
        {
            return AuthenticationSchemes.None;
        }
    }
```